# Type errors in angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I got this code from a book, however, in the original code, he initializes the formgroup in the OnInit() method.
That's why the following errors are not present. However, I think this is wrong as he is trying to hack his way around the main issue.

the original code:

```
export class CityEditComponent implements OnInit {

  
  // the form model
  form! : FormGroup


  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData();
    form = new FormGroup({
     name: new FormControl(''),
     lat: new FormControl(''),
     lon: new FormControl('')
});
  }
```

The way I think it should be, but with errors:

City interface:

```
export interface City {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  lat: number;
  lon: number;
}
```

CityEditComponent:

```
export class CityEditComponent implements OnInit {

  // the form model
  form = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(''),
    lat: new FormControl(''),
    lon: new FormControl('')
  });

ngOnInit() {
  this.loadData();
}

loadData() {

  .. getting a city object from a backend server...

    // update the form with the city value
    this.form.patchValue(this.city); -> error because city.lan is a number and formcontrol.lan is string
  };
}

onSubmit() {
  var city = this.city;
  if (city) {
    city.name = this.form.controls['name'].value; -> error because city.name is not null and formcontrol.name maybe null
    city.lat = +this.form.controls['lat'].value; -> error: Object is possibly null
    city.lon = +this.form.controls['lon'].value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are some type mismatches and null/undefined values in your code that need to be handled. I have rewritten the code. Check if this helps.

```
export class CityEditComponent implements OnInit {
    // checking whether the city is defined before trying to access its properties or assign values to it.
    city?: City;

    // the form model
    form = new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl(null), // Initialized with null
        lat: new FormControl(null),
        lon: new FormControl(null)
    });
    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadData();
    }
    loadData() {
        // ... getting a city object from a backend server...

        // update the form with the city value
        if (this.city) {
            this.form.patchValue({
                name: this.city.name,
                lat: this.city.lat.toString(), // Convert city.lan to string
                lon: this.city.lon.toString()  // Convert city.lon to string
            });
        }
    }
    onSubmit() {
        if (this.city) {
            const nameControl = this.form.controls['name'];
            const latControl = this.form.controls['lat'];
            const lonControl = this.form.controls['lon'];
            // Adding checks to ensure that the form control values are not null before accessing them
            if (nameControl.value !== null) {
                this.city.name = nameControl.value;
            }
            if (latControl.value !== null) {
                this.city.lat = +latControl.value; // Converting string to number
            }
            if (lonControl.value !== null) {
                this.city.lon = +lonControl.value; // Converting string to number
            }
        }
    }
}
```